# UITableViewController with TableView and a non scrolling footer view

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'd like to implement something that looks like a media player, a playlist in table view that takes 3/4th of the screen height and a 1/4 height fixed panel at the bottom for play controls. I can't add anything to my UITableViewController in Storyboard, it only allows adding something to my TableView. How should this be done in iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `UITableViewController` inherits `fromUIViewController`. There is two possibilities to add others element with your tableview :

- In the `viewDidLoad` method of your table view controller, replace it's view (it is its table view at the moment) by a new view, resize the table view, and add a view at the bottom programmatically.
- Replace your `UITableViewController` in your storyboard by a simple `UIVIewController`. You add in it your tableview, your bottom view, and everithing else you want. In the header file of your view controller, specified it implements the delegates methods for a tableview :

  `@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>`

  And don't forget to assign the delegate and datasource of your tableview in the IB to this view controller.

  Then write the methods required for a tableview datasource and delegate (tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: , numberOfSectionInTableView:,...)

Comment: As far as I can see UITableViewController is just an interface declaring that it implements data source and table delegate. Why does it impose restrictions on its contents?

Comment: Well, I don't know. I've designed an app with a top bar for almost every view, and had to designed all my TableViewComtroller from a simple ViewController implementing datasource et delegates methods for tableview

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm taking this approach.